# Wine opens "Wine application loader" instead of Microsoft Word

Tags: office, wine

I know that you will tell me that I should use Libreoffice, but I have an Office licence and I still use it.

I use Wine to run Office 2007 but when I launch Word or any Office app, Wine launches a "Wine application loader" instead of the real Word app.

How can I display the actual Word icon on Plank?

Comment: `<unhelpful cmmt>`I'm sorry but Office 2007?? Do yourself a favor and just use Libreoffice.`</unhelpful cmmt>`

Comment: Based on Microsoft's product support, mainstream support for Office 2007  is over, and you will likely find Wine depreciating it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=8753 As such, this unhelpful comment is probably not that unhelpful, although there are many other alternatives that can be seen here http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/113/26

Answer (score 4):

If you have problems with starting MS Office with wine (silent crashes, etc.) then you might be missing some libraries (`.dll`) or you haven't properly installed it (You can install most of them through `Winetricks`).

To troubleshoot it, try running it through terminal like this:

`wine /path/to/office/winword.exe`

you should get some error details.

As with icons, similar questions have been answered [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/android-studio-blurry-second-icon-on-plank/1058#1058) and [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-can-i-fix-the-fuzzy-google-chrome-icon-that-appears-in-plank). To get the icon you want on plank, you need to create a .desktop file and put it in either :

`~/.local/share/applications`  **(your profile only)**

or

`/usr/share/applications` **(everyone, requires sudo access !)**.

Briefly, it should look something like this:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=MS Word
Exec=wine /path/to/office/winword.exe
Icon=/path/to/your/MS\ Word/Icon/icon.png
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=Winword.exe`

Also, if you are used to MS Office look and feel, maybe you could give Kingsoft office a try.